# SailsJS through association: how to create association?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I'm using **Sails 0.12.3** and **postgresql 9.3.4** on Mac OSX (10.10.5), and I'm attempting to implement a [through association](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations)

I've set up two models with a third as the join table. When I attempt to test that it is all set up by creating a relationship I get this error:

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'via' of undefined
> ```

Here's my **test** (**mocha/chai**) -- I think the error is actually in this method of creating the association (since if I create the model for the join as a separate call it works:

```
  describe('with orgs', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      var testEmail = 'sue@test.com';
      var orgName = 'Awesome Org';
      Org.create({name:orgName})
      .then(function(org) {
        return User.create({username:testEmail, orgs:[org]})
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        done()
      })
      .catch(done);
    });
    it('populates empty list of orgs', function(done) {
      console.log('about to call find');
      User.find().populate('orgs')
      .then(function(users) {
        console.log('users', users);
        var user = users[0]
        assert.isNotNull(user.orgs);
        assert.equal(user.orgs.length, 1);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
    });
  });
```

Here are my models:

**User.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username : { type: 'email' },
    orgs: {
      collection: 'org',
      via: 'user',
      through: 'orgmembership'
    }
  }
};
```

**Org.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name : 'string',
    users: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'org',
      through: 'orgmembership'
    }
  },
};
```

**OrgMembership.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'org_membership',
  attributes: {
    user: { model: 'User', columnName: 'user_id', foreignKey: true},
    org: { model: 'Org',  columnName: 'org_id', foreignKey: true}
  }
};
```

I've posted the whole project on [github](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/sails-many-to-many/tree/related-postgres).

I found this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570740/how-to-implement-many-to-many-association-using-through-in-sails), which seems to be doing the same thing, and attempted to follow the same pattern, but it's not working for me.

I would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this was a bug in Waterline and has been patched as of Waterline@0.11.5. I tested with your project and it worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Users.js should refer to "users" in the "via" definition in Org.js, the same applies to OrgMembership.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username : { type: 'email' },
    orgs: {
      collection: 'org',
      via: 'users',
      through: 'orgmembership'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: The deisgn is that every orgmembership should have a single user and a single org, it doesn't make sense to me that those would be plural in OrgMembership.  I tried it anyhow and it didn't work for me -- the test still fails.

Comment: here's the change that I tried based on your suggestion:  https://github.com/ultrasaurus/sails-many-to-many/commit/2b65e1f294da617693a670541c704a4a04aed4bf

Comment: Sails is simply trying to reference the collection, which is your physical file that you've created "org.js", "user.js" etc so the "collection" value must match the name given to that file. the "via" assignment is the attribute that denotes the association and should also match the field defined in the model explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your comment.  It seems consistent with the change I made that still didn't work.  What am I missing?